# Network monitoring systems

Tags: networking, service, monitoring

I am trying to find a good network monitoring system, easy to configure and to still have a lot of features. I want to try Nagio but it seems to be very complicated. I saw that are also a lot of systems direved from it (or work with it), like groundwork or Shinken.

Do you know or recommend a good solution for this?

Comment: You may have better luck on serverfault.com; entirely too many are listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems  (I've only heard of munin, nagios, cacti, and collectd, but that might just be my ignorance rather than their dominance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use GroundWork Community version. It runs Nagios inside already. Very hand one try it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use zenoss  , monitoring system , groundwork community or enterprise 
 opsview etc

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [New Relic](http://www.getapp.com/reviews/listing/new-relic-application). It is super easy to use.